# OpenVPN and DNS recursion

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, debian, openvpn

I've set up an internal DNS with Bind9 on a Debian9 device so that my colleagues can call our public cloud infrastructure hostnames to connect to the servers on their private interfaces.

I've set up an OpenVPN server on a Debian 9 device so my colleagues can access our public cloud infrastructure from its private interfaces. I'd like them to connect to the servers using their hostnames so I've set up a Bind9 DNS server. I have not allowed recursion on this server for security reasons. My colleagues need to have access to internet while connected to the VPN.

When I push the DNS and domain configuration to Windows clients I ether :

- Can use internet but not resolve servers' hostname (commented block-outside-dns) : the clients only use the ISP's DNS
- Can resolve servers hostnames but not use internet (uncommented block-outside-dns) : the clients only use the internal DNS

I guess the problem comes from the fact that Windows only tries one DNS if it's reachable and not the other ones on other interfaces. Is there any way to make the Windows clients use the internal DNS for VPN traffic and the ISP's DNS for internet traffic ? Do I have no other choice than to allow recursion on the internal DNS server ?

OpenVPN DNS configuration :

```
push "dhcp-option DNS X.X.X.X"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN mydomain.com"
push "register-dns"
push "block-outside-dns"
```

------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------

So apparently, Windows can only ask one DNS to resolve names. It will not try the other DNS if it gets a negative response from the first one. In my case it means that Windows will ask the ISP's DNS when I try to connect to a servers' hostname and never ask the internal DNS. The only workaround to this I can think of is to connect to servers using FQDN, which I try to avoid since it can be quite long. I could also allow recursion on the internal DNS but I tried to avoid it, since I don't want all DNS queries to be routed to the internal DNS.

Comment: FYI a [recent post](https://serverfault.com/a/1005341/377666) touching on the same issue. Note: "`--block-outside-dns` - Block DNS servers on other network adapters to prevent DNS leaks. This option prevents any application from accessing TCP or UDP port 53 except one inside the tunnel."

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make the your internal DNS resolve queries for you clients to get that to work unfortunately. But, you can set it up as such that they'll use the internal DNS to resolve everything, but you only tunnel traffic to your internal IP ranges. That way your clients get DNS query answers, but they'll use their normal uplink to actually send traffic to those remote hosts on the Internet.

Comment: I would have go for this but I'm not really sure I should use our internal DNS to answer all DNS queries. I don't really know what the best practices are for this kind of configuration. It could lead to conflicts for some of my colleagues who may have set up their own DNS.

Comment: Well, most DNS servers when provided with no config will resolve anything, so I'd say to first check if your internal DNS already answers all queries. Also, if you have multiple DNS servers authoritative for multiple internal zones, you can use conditional forwarders to make sure they forward internal queries to the right DNS servers.